# How to display the pie chart legend with proper style so that the chart is visible

Tags: css, user-interface, charts, highcharts, legend

I am using high charts wants to show the legend as shown below
[image]
tried many combination just wanted to know can i move the legend to the left or make the legend transparent so that both image and legend looks correctly to the user

Problem is when i show the legend the names of the chart are overlapping

please help me with the css

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/navigation/

```
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 30,
    navigation: {
        activeColor: '#3E576F',
        animation: true,
        arrowSize: 12,
        inactiveColor: '#CCC',
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: '#333',
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.navigation